# Extract file names from PCollection and parse them efficiently

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a BigQuery table where each row represent a text file (gs://...) and a line number.

```
file, line, meta
file1.txt, 10, meta1
file2.txt, 12, meta2
file1.txt, 198, meta3
```

Each file is about 1.5Gb and there are about 1k files in the my bucket. My goal is extract lines specified in the BQ table.

I decided to implement the following plan:

1. Map `table` => `KV<file,line>`
2. Reduce `KV<file,line>` => `KV<file, [lines]>`
3. Map `KV<file, [lines]>` => `[KV<file, rowData>]`

where `rowData` means actual data from `file` on the some line from `lines`.

If I read docs and SO carefully, `TextIO.Read` isn't supposed to be used in such conditions. As a workaround I can use `GcsIoChannelFactory` to read files from GCS. Is it correct? Is it a preferable approach for the described task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct. There is currently no better approach to reading lines with line numbers from text files, except for doing it yourself using `GcsIoChannelFactory` (or writing a custom `FileBasedSource`, but this is more complex, and wouldn't work in your case because the filenames are not known in advance).

This and other similar scenarios will get much better with [Splittable DoFn](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-65) - work on that is in progress, but it is a large amount of work, so no timeline yet.